# how to fetch data from multiple tables without doing join in sqlalchemy (Using fastApi)

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

```
class Actions(Base):
    __tablename__ = "actions"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    resource_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('resources.id'))
    action_short_name = Column(String(20),nullable=True)
    description = Column(String(250),nullable=True)
    status = Column(String(1),nullable=True)
    action_resource = relation(Resource, backref = "actions")

detailsQ = session.query(Actions).join(Resource).filter(Actions.resource_id == Resource.id).all()
```

I don't want to use join so how I am able to fetch data though I have made relations ?

Comment: Without the code of the route, it is difficoult to say. That being said, `join`s are the preferred way of achieving what you're trying to achieve and there's no point in not doing so

Comment: `Resource.actions`? Since that's what you have `backref`'d - if your goal is to avoid explicitly typing the `query(Actions).join(...)` part when you already have relationship defined.